# How do I fit the content inside this div if max-width to the parent div is given

Tags: css, storybook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQWds.png)

I am using a container with max-width of 80% and after extending the text the container is stuck at 80% rather than being flexible according to the text.
Someone please give a solution to it

Comment: Post your code so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it will be super useful if you share the code, not the picture. As I understood the problem -> if you have less the, than 80% of the block, the block width should be equal to the content width -> width of the text. Correct?
Here is an example:

```
<div class="test">
  here is the text, which I can make bigger and everything will still take 80% maximum
</div>

.test {
  background: red;
  max-width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Please, correct me if I understood smth wrong.
Thank you.